# xpath in cypress could not use a click acitivity?

Tags: cypress, cypress-xpath

In my project I am using xpath in cypress(I have installed as instruction did not make an error)

where

cy.xpath("//span[@class='ui-button-text ui-c']").click()

click()-> function is avaiable but I receive a error

""can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 24 elements. ""

Why it is and how do i solve this issue!!!?

Comment: Your issue is in the error message - your query yields more than one element, and `cy.click()` can only be called on a singular element. Can you provide a sample HTML? The solution is to make sure your `cy.xpath` yields only one element, or you use a filtering command like `cy.eq()` or `cy.first()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.